# setpgid makes interactive programs (vim, emacs... ncurses ?) to infinite loops

Tags: c, linux, shell

I'm trying to recode a shell and I would like to change the pgid of my programs launched with my shell !

I tried to do differents functions after my `fork()` :

- `setpgid(0, 0)` that makes interactive programs like vim, emacs... to do an infinite loop
- `setsid()` that doesn't deserve control to the terminal. It makes
  programs like emacs failed with `Could not open file: /dev/tty`
- `tcsetpgrp(0, getpid())` that make my shell to go to background !

> ```
> #include      <unistd.h>
> #include      <stdlib.h>
> #include      <stdio.h>
>
> int           main(void)
> {
>   int         pid;
>
>   if ((pid = fork()) == 0)
>   {
>     setpgid(0, 0);
>     execlp("/usr/bin/emacs", "", "-nw", "test_file", (char*)0);
>   }
>   if (pid < 0)
>     exit (1);
>   if (pid > 0)
>   {
>     printf("Program finished.\n");
>     waitpid(-1, 0, 0);
>   }
>   return (0);
> }
> ```

Have you got a clue about how to solve that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I find the solution to make work emacs program like emacs, vim etc.. that needs to control the terminal !

I had to add control to the terminal into the parent, like that :

```
#include      <unistd.h>
#include      <stdlib.h>
#include      <stdio.h>

int           main(void)
{
  int         pid;

  if ((pid = fork()) == 0)
  {
    setpgid(0, 0);
    execlp("/usr/bin/emacs", "", "-nw", "test_file", (char*)0);
  }
  if (pid < 0)
    exit (1);
  if (pid > 0)
  {
    tcsetpgrp(0, pid)
    printf("Program finished.\n");
    waitpid(-1, 0, 0);
  }
  return (0);
```

}

If you want more informations : Here is a good link http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Launching-Jobs.html